# Outlook Add-in for Calendar

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, icalendar

I'm really new at add-in stuff. My code should do these: 
An outlook user saves/creates anything. If the created item is an appointment item my system must save it under the c: directory, taking the item subject as file name. Here is my code. What is wrong there?

Note: when I create a new appointment the if clause is working, if I write there any other code, it is working, but I can't get the ai's info, such as `ai.Subject`.

```
namespace SendToMRBS
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           this.Application.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(Application_ItemLoad);
    }

    void Application_ItemLoad(object Item)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            Outlook.AppointmentItem ai = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            ai.SaveAs("C:\\" + ai.Subject, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olICal);
        }
    }


    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.. The Item object has no properties or something, so I had to use NewInspector event. Here is my new code:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(Application_ItemLoad);

    }

    void Application_ItemLoad(object Item)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
        }
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem ai = Inspector.CurrentItem;
        ai.Write += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_WriteEventHandler(ai_Write);
    }

    void ai_Write(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.Inspector ins = this.Application.ActiveInspector();
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appi = ins.CurrentItem;

        appi.SaveAs("c:\\test.ics", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olICal);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion

}
```